# Create WCF application in a metro app

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to create a WCF service inside Visual Studio 2012 metro app solution file?
When I try to add a new project, I don't see [WCF Service] template. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a supported scenario for Modern UI applications.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/43df6c8f-f1e3-4aba-af0a-7c4e1db477b6/